# Babel loader issue "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders" `/@react-spring/web/dist/`

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, yarnpkg, react-spring

I am currently forking uniswap for a testnet not a live application

I have tied in the testnet and deployed the contracts. Before doing this I was able to get it into a docker container.

After doing this I am running

`yarn upgrade`

`NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

`yarn add immer jotai-immer`

Then

`yarn start`

This previously got the application started locally now I get this error

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@react-spring/web/dist/esm/index.js 113:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (113:11)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       this.transforms = i;
|     }
>     _value = null;
|     get() {
|       return this._value || (this._value = this._get());
```

I've never seen it before, can anyone provide a fix or pinpoint the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after I had updated @react-spring/web to the latest version. I rolled the version back to "9.6.1". Now it works.